# Twig is unable create cache directory

Tags: php, symfony, caching, twig, symfony-2.5

This is the error

> RuntimeException: Unable to create the cache directory (1/25/20).
>
> 1- Changing the cache directory in the appKernel file didn't fix the problem

```
/*
        public function getCacheDir()
        {
            return '/mnt/symfony_ram_cache/cache/'.$this->environment;
        }
*/
```

> 2- Setting the permissions to "chmod 777 -R cache" didn't work, still throws the error
>
> 3- App works when I deactivate the twig cache (I obviously need it in production)

```
#Twig Configuration
twig:
   cache: false
```

> 4- It DOES create several folders in cache (in both prod and dev) when I empty the cache directoy and reload, so what means the rights are actually set properly

[image: screenshot]

> 5- Here is a screenshot of the error

[image: error screenshot]

> 6- PS: Updated to symfony 2.5.6 the twig bundle was updated but still have no luck

Comment: Don't clear cache directory itself, To clear cache just remove directories/files inside that.

Comment: @ApulGupta 
That's what I meant by clearing it, I'll edit the post to avoid further confusion

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should `chown` cache directory to user who fires up application (www-data?)?

Answer (score 0):

Edit your

```
app/config/config.yml
```

And change this:

From:

```
twig:
     cache:            "%kernel.debug%"
```

To:

```
twig:
     cache:            "%kernel.cache_dir%/twig"
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what was wrong, I installed symfony2 from scratch again and now it works.